# What's the difference between system() in C and Perl?

Tags: c, perl, process, system

The `system()` function will launch a new process from C and a Perl script.

What exactly are the differences between processes called by `system()` in C and from Perl scripts, in terms of representation of error codes?

Answer (score 8):

A little research brings up:

> The return value is the exit status of
>   the program as returned by the wait
>   call. To get the actual exit value,
>   shift right by eight (see below). See
>   also "exec". This is not what you want
>   to use to capture the output from a
>   command, for that you should use
>   merely backticks or qx//, as described
>   in "`STRING`" in perlop. Return value
>   of -1 indicates a failure to start the
>   program or an error of the wait(2)
>   system call (inspect $! for the
>   reason).

And the docs of `wait` say:

> Behaves like the wait(2) system call
>   on your system: it waits for a child
>   process to terminate and returns the
>   pid of the deceased process, or -1  if
>   there are no child processes. The
>   status is returned in $? and
>   ${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE} . Note that a
>   return value of -1  could mean that
>   child processes are being
>   automatically reaped, as described in
>   perlipc.

---

Sources: This was taken from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). Here's a [tutorial on system](http://perl.about.com/od/programmingperl/qt/perlexecsystem.htm) in Perl.

Comment: @eliben, could you please provide me some more information or some link to work on these in detail

Comment: @Sachin: linked to the sources

Comment: The docs for C `system()` say exactly the same -- it returns -1 on failure to fork, and the result of `wait()` otherwise.

Comment: I hate links to spammy about.com